# responsive design toggle html divs content with css classes to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Are there any jQuery plugins that can help me with toggling html content and css classes for a responsive design?

As the below image will illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, I'd like to know if there is something that can help me with this beside managing this myself using jQuery (e.g. `var conteOfOneBlock = $('.someclass .ablock').html();` )

[image: responsive design - reorder elements]

Comment: I think you could do what you want without jQuery (just media queries).

Comment: @waston: Thanks! If you don't mind can you send me a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .

Comment: uh... just google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). That's where you change the CSS applied to elements in order to respond to specific viewport widths / heights / etc.

For instance, you could make `A` and `B` `float: left` only if the viewport is larger than a given size:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .A, .B { float : left; }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of media queries, I'm look some jQuery plugins that would help me in the media queries to achieve that...

Comment: What exactly are you not able to do with just media queries?

Comment: @el.severo: Media queries are CSS. jQuery is JavaScript. Why do you think you need a jQuery plug-in to help you with media queries?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: as far as I know the DOM can be manipulated only with DOM, when I say manipulate I mean changing the hierarchy

Comment: @el.severo: There's nothing in your question that can't be done purely with media queries and CSS. Certainly just deciding whether to float A and B left can be (as I've shown).